# Как задать значение в столбце значением другого столбца при UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно заменить значение NULL на то которое в соседнем столбце.
Таблица такого плана:

```
id value_1    value_2
1  NULL       строка_1
2  строка_2   строка_3
```

Как написать UPDATE чтобы вместо NULL вставилась строка из колонки value_2? При этом если в колонке value_1 не NULL то все должно остаться как есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update mytable set value_1 = value_2 where value_1 is null
```